# How to solve ODE with sine involved (comparison of coefficients)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I thought I grasped it thanks to an answer to a similar question I posed, but it seems a little trickier:

Given $y' = y\,\sin(x)+\sin(2\,x)$, trying to solve with the same approach:

$y_p = a_0\,\sin(2\,x)+b_0\,\cos(2\,x)$

so that:

$\begin{align}
{y_p}' &= 2\,a_0\cos(2\,x) -2\,b_0\,\sin(2\,x)\\
 &= y\,\sin(x)+\sin(2\,x) \\
&= a_0\,\sin(2\,x)\,\sin(x)+b_0\,\cos(2\,x)\,\sin(x) + \sin(2\,x)
\end{align}$

Unlike the other inquiry no comparison of coefficients seems possible due to the multiplication.

Is there something to be done still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) works for [linear ODE with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Non-homogeneous_equation_with_constant_coefficients). The given ODE is a [linear ODE with variable coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients).

After multiplying both sides by the **integral factor** $e^{\cos(x)}$, the given linear ODE is equivalent to
$$D(e^{\cos(x)}y(x))=e^{\cos(x)}\sin(2x).$$
Now integrate the RHS:
$$\begin{align}
\int e^{\cos(x)}\sin(2x)\,dx&=2\int e^{\cos(x)}\cos(x)\sin(x)\,dx\\
&=-2\int e^{t}t\,dt=-2e^t(t-1)+c\\
&=-2e^{\cos(x)}(\cos(x)-1)+c.
\end{align}$$
Hence the general solution is
$$y(x)=ce^{-\cos(x)}+\underbrace{2(1-\cos(x))}_{\text{particular solution}}.$$
Note that the particular solution $y_p(x)=2(1-\cos(x))$ is not of the form:
$a_0\sin(2x)+b_0\cos(2x)$. Indeed $y_p(0)=0=b_0$ and $y_p(\pi)=4=b_0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: wow, that's so shrewd, thank you!